# System.InvalidOperationException при попытке выполнить процедуру из EF

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

В общем, хочу наполнить сущность через процедуру.

Ради теста я в эту процедуру добавили SELECT * FROM [TableName]

Так вот, я ловлю ошибку:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated
>   was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
>   Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or
>   FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client
>   side.'

Вот тут:

```
var result = pdContext.Users.FromSqlInterpolated($"GetTest").ToList();
```

Если я туда напрямую загоню запрос, на выборку, то все работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Пробовал и EXEC прописывать, но не помогло...

Comment: А у вас хранимая процедура ил функция? Процедуры не имеют возможность возвращать табличный тип данных, а вот функции могут.

Comment: Процедура. Однако, я уже ранее мапил процедуру, правда там я указывал для модели HasNoKey.